# отсортировать строки по алфавиту

Tags: c++, массивы, строки, классы

Изначально задание выглядит так: Создайте класс с именем train, содержащую поля: название пункта назначения, номер поезда, время отправления. Ввести данные в массив из пяти элементов типа train, упорядочить элементы по номерам поездов. Добавить возможность вывода информации о поезде, номер которого введен пользователем. Добавить возможность сортировки массив по пункту назначения, причем поезда с одинаковыми пунктами назначения должны быть упорядочены по времени отправления.
я застрял на моменте, где надо добавить возможность сортировки по пункту назначения(сортировать по алфавиту). Подскажите как это можно реализовать

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class train 
{
public:

    string destination;
    int tnumber;
    int dp_hour;
    int dp_min;

};

int main()
{   
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    const int size = 2;
    train arr[size];

    //ввод
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << "Укажите данные поезда " << i + 1 << "\n\nВведите место назначения: ";
        getline(cin, arr[i].destination);
        cout << "Введите номер поезда: ";
        cin >> arr[i].tnumber;
        cout << "Время отправления поезда: \n\tЧас:";
        cin >> arr[i].dp_hour;
        cout << "\tМинута: ";
        cin >> arr[i].dp_min;
        cout << "\n";
        cin.ignore();
    }

    //сортировка
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {
            if (arr[i].tnumber > arr[j].tnumber) {
                train tmp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }

    //вывод инфы о поезде
    char check = '+';
    while (check != '-') {
        cout << "Необходимо ли узнать информацию о поезде?(«+» - да, «-» - нет): ";
        cin >> check;
        if (check == '+') {
            int index;
            cout << "Введите номер поезда: ";
            cin >> index;
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                if (index == arr[i].tnumber) {
                    cout << "Пункт назначения: " << arr[i].destination << "\nВремя отправления: " << arr[i].dp_hour << ":" << arr[i].dp_min;
                }
            }
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    
    //сортировка по пункту назначения


    /* for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << arr[i].destination << " ";
    } */

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хорошо подумайте, нужна ли Вам оптимизация сортировки. Я обычно ее побаиваюсь..
Код сортировки по возрастанию:

```
//сортировка
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        if ( arr[i].tnumber < arr[j].tnumber ) {
            train tmp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = tmp;
        }
    }
} 

    //сортировка по месту
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            if (arr[i].destination < arr[j].destination && arr[i].tnumber== arr[j].tnumber) {
                train tmp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: В вопросе речь о сортировке по строкам

Comment: Строки сравниваются так же, как и int в c++. Возможно, основная проблема в том, что должна быть группировка еще и по отсортированным номерам, тогда условие во втором блоке должно работать..